# CRM 2016 OrganizationServiceProxy.EnableProxyTypes seems to hang

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2016

We're currently changing the architecture of our back end systems and we've discovered that we need to enable proxy types for use in CodeActivities for Workflows, using the OrganizationServiceProxy.EnableProxyTypes method.

However, whenever I include this method call it makes the Workflow run extremely slow before eventually failing.

Here is the code we use to call the method:

```
    var service = serviceFactory.CreateOrganizationService(context.UserId);
    if (service is OrganizationService)
    {
        tracingService.Trace("Enabling proxy types");
        ((OrganizationServiceProxy)((OrganizationService)service).InnerService).EnableProxyTypes(assembly);
        tracingService.Trace("Proxy types enabled");
    }
```

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: "we've discovered that we need to enable proxy types for use in CodeActivities for Workflows" maybe you want to use, but surely you don't need

Answer (score 0):

I've never had to pass an assembly in as a parameter to EnableProxyTypes.  Did you try it without passing the assembly?

Also, there's another way to enable proxy types by adding to the Behaviors collection.  Here's an example:

```csharp
public static IOrganizationService GetOrganizationService(Guid userId)
{
    ClientCredentials credentials = new ClientCredentials();
    credentials.Windows.ClientCredential = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials;
    Uri homeRealmUri = null;

    using (OrganizationServiceProxy _serviceProxy = new OrganizationServiceProxy(new Uri(GetOrganizationUri()),
        homeRealmUri, credentials, null))
    {
        _serviceProxy.ServiceConfiguration.CurrentServiceEndpoint.Behaviors.Add(new ProxyTypesBehavior());
        _serviceProxy.CallerId = userId;

        IOrganizationService _service = (IOrganizationService)_serviceProxy;
        return _service;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response but we've decided to go down a different route so this is no longer applicable.